# Error using the less than or equal to operator in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

When I use the < or the <= operator in my Angular 6 template, I get a typescript/parse error ( < turns red in VS Code, and does not work, but no console errors).  The greater than (>) sign works great.  Does anyone have a fix or workaround? Or, how to turn this into a function in the component.ts?
I'm trying to display green text if the number (dem.econDisadvPercent) is less than or equal to 5. 
I've read the few posts on this and do not understand how to fix it (https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues/70).

```
 <div *ngFor="let dem of demographicsAll; let in = index">
  <div *ngIf="dem.econDisadvPercent <= 5 " [ngStyle]="{'background-color': dem.econDisadvPercent? 'green' : 'red'}">  
    <h4> {{ dem.econDisadvPercent }} </h4>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by reversing my colors and using greater than, which works.  But, I would still like to know how to fix the error when using the less than operator ...(?)